# Using `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` with `seq2seq.sequence_loss()`

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

I have a working RNN using the default softmax loss function for `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss()` (which I'm assuming is `tf.nn.softmax()`) but would instead like to use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`. According to the [seq2seq.sequence_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss) documentation, one may use `softmax_loss_function=` to override the default loss function:

> **softmax_loss_function**: Function (labels, logits) -> loss-batch to be
>   used instead of the standard softmax (the default if this is None).
>   Note that to avoid confusion, it is required for the function to
>   accept named arguments.

Here is my code that works:

```
from tensorflow.python.layers.core import Dense

# Build the graph
train_graph = tf.Graph()
# Set the graph to default to ensure that it is ready for training
with train_graph.as_default():

    # Load the model inputs    
    input_data, targets, keep_prob, lr, target_sequence_length, max_target_sequence_length, source_sequence_length \
    = get_model_inputs()

    # Create the training and inference logits
    training_decoder_output, inference_decoder_output = seq2seq_model(input_data, 
                                                                      targets, 
                                                                      lr, 
                                                                      target_sequence_length, 
                                                                      max_target_sequence_length, 
                                                                      source_sequence_length,
                                                                      len(source_letter_to_int),
                                                                      len(target_letter_to_int),
                                                                      encoding_embedding_size, 
                                                                      decoding_embedding_size, 
                                                                      rnn_size, 
                                                                      num_layers,
                                                                      keep_prob)    

    # Create tensors for the training logits and inference logits
    training_logits = tf.identity(training_decoder_output.rnn_output, 'logits')
    inference_logits = tf.identity(inference_decoder_output.sample_id, name='predictions')

    # Create the weights for sequence_loss
    masks = tf.sequence_mask(target_sequence_length, max_target_sequence_length, dtype=tf.float32, name='masks')

    with tf.name_scope("optimization"):

        # Loss function
        cost = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(training_logits, targets, masks)

        # Optimizer
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)

        # Gradient Clipping
        gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
        capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
        train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)

        # Add variables to collection in order to load them up when retraining a saved graph
        tf.add_to_collection("cost", cost)
        tf.add_to_collection("train_op", train_op)
```

My attempt to change the loss function is as follows (I've only indicated the code that is different):

```
with tf.name_scope("optimization"):

    # One-hot encode targets and reshape to match logits, one row per batch_size per step
    y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(targets, len(target_letter_to_int))
    y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y_one_hot, [batch_size, len(target_letter_to_int), 30])

    # Loss function
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=training_logits, labels=y_reshaped)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    cost = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(training_logits, targets, masks, softmax_loss_function=loss)
```

The line `cost = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(training_logits, targets, masks, softmax_loss_function=loss)` is now giving me "**TypeError**: 'Tensor' object is not callable." This is one of the most opaque errors I've seen Tensorflow produce and I haven't found much of anything in the way of explanation on the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation, softmax_loss_function is a Function (labels, logits) -> loss-batch to be used instead of the standard softmax (the default if this is None). **Note that to avoid confusion, it is required for the function to accept named arguments.** 
So you should write, softmax_loss_function= tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Comment: Thanks. I totally didn't get that until now, but now it's clear. I'm contemplating deleting this question. What do you think?

Comment: Also, I just dug into the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/loss.py) and `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` already uses `nn_ops.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` by default, so there's no need to even do this.